# Is there a P4 keyword that expands just to YYYY?

Tags: perforce

I was wondering if there is a keyword in P4 that expands to just YYYY, I'd like to automatically ensure that the copyright year is uptodate when a file is changed.

The $DATE keyword expands to more than just the year, so that doesn't quite work.

Thanks

Comment: One possibility would be a change-commit trigger. It would be pretty straightforward to write a trigger which looked at the file to see if the copyright year needed updating, and then automatically performed the copyright change (as a separate follow-on submit) if needed.